# DolphinDB: How to filter data in a sliding window?

Tags: filtering, window-functions, dolphindb

From the data observed for the pervious n days, I want to select the bars with trading volumn exceeding 50% of the total trading volume. Then, I wish to calculate the sum of returns for the selected bars using the `msum` function.

But I don’t know how to filter the bars within a sliding window. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `iif` function within `msum` to specify the filtering condition.

Refer to the script below:

```
tbl=table(rand(100, 20) as `vol, rand(10.0, 20) as `ret)
n=5
select msum(iif(vol > 0.5 * msum(vol, n), ret, 0), n) from tbl
```